# Is it possible to store 2 different struct types in the same column of a data bricks delta table?

Tags: azure-databricks, delta, apache-spark-xml

I'm receiving multiple XML files that need to be loaded into one table. Those XML files have different struct types for a particular column. I'm wondering if somehow this column could be stored in the same column of a data bricks table. please refer below for the different struct types I'm getting for the same column col1. In file1 col1 is struct and col1a is struct and col1a1, col1a2..are string types
for file2 same col1 is a struct type but underlying col1b and col1c are string types.

file1 :
col1
col1a
col1a1
col1a2
.
.
col1b

file2:
col1
col1b
col1c

Answer (score 0):

Read the two xmls saperatly then convert the data type of the 2 col to string or struct depending on your choice for respective dataframes.Finally do a union on the two data frames.